# JSON Schema Validation - Accessing different properties from within an If,Then,Else statement

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

im hoping you guys can help me understand how to access multiple properties from within an If statement from different parrts of the payload. I have an example of below. The problem i have is that i need the then  and else statements to work across the contents of each item within the array. It currently only works when there is only one item in the array.

Schema:

```json
{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [
            {
                "properties": {
                    "report_body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "afs_employee_director_rep": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "afs_emp_rep_Capacity": {
                                            "contains": {
                                                "const": "Current director of licensee"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "afs_emp_rep_Capacity"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "properties": {
                    "report_body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "licensees_schemes_rep_involved": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "report_submit_licensee": {
                                        "const": "Yes"
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": [
                                    "report_submit_licensee"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "report_body": {
                "properties": {
                    "afs_employee_director_rep": {
                        "items": {
                            "required": [
                                "afs_emp_rep_verify"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "else": {
        "not": {
            "properties": {
                "report_body": {
                    "properties": {
                        "afs_employee_director_rep": {
                            "items": {
                                "required": [
                                    "afs_emp_rep_verify"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fails validation as expected:

```json
{
    "report_body": {
        "licensees_schemes_rep_involved": {
            "report_submit_licensee": "Yes",
            "report_licensee_types": "AFS licence",
            "report_responsible_entity": "No",
            "report_cciv_corporate_dir": "No",
            "report_committed_entity": "Representative(s)",
            "representative_ReportableSituationRelate": "Employee/director of licensee or related body corporate (who is not a financial adviser)"
        },
        "other_afs_licensees": [
            "234563"
        ],
        "afs_employee_director_rep": [
            {
                "afs_emp_rep_Capacity": [
                    "Current director of licensee"
                ],
                "afs_emp_rep_work_monitored": "No",
                "afs_emp_rep_verify_1": "No"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this does not:

```json
{
    "report_body": {
        "licensees_schemes_rep_involved": {
            "report_submit_licensee": "Yes",
            "report_licensee_types": "AFS licence",
            "report_responsible_entity": "No",
            "report_cciv_corporate_dir": "No",
            "report_committed_entity": "Representative(s)",
            "representative_ReportableSituationRelate": "Employee/director of licensee or related body corporate (who is not a financial adviser)"
        },
        "other_afs_licensees": [
            "234563"
        ],
        "afs_employee_director_rep": [
            {
                "afs_emp_rep_Capacity": [
                    "Current director of licensee"
                ],
                "afs_emp_rep_work_monitored": "No",
                "afs_emp_rep_verify_1": "No"
            },
            {
                "afs_emp_rep_Capacity": [
                    "Former director of licensee"
                ],
                "afs_emp_rep_work_monitored": "No",
                "afs_emp_rep_verify_1": "No"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you the schema you shared is correct? The `required` property of in the `allOf` section is inside the `properties` attribute instead of next to it. If I fix that, both your examples validate just fine for me.

Comment: Heya sorry you're right. i've fixed that. the problem still exists as it doesn't validate for each item in the array. i.e if you have multiple objects in the array i need the property within each object validated. not just across the whole array.

Comment: so, in your second example, the second employee in `afs_employee_director_rep` (with "Former director of licensee") is OK to NOT have the `afs_emp_rep_verify` key but for the first one (with "Current director of licensee") the key is required?

Answer (score 0):

I'd re-write it using a nested `oneOf`: each `afs_employee_director_rep` entry needs to either not contain the "Current director of licensee" string or, if it contains it, it also requires the `afs_emp_rep_verify` key.

```json
{
  "allOf":[
    {
      "properties":{
        "report_body":{
          "properties":{
            "afs_employee_director_rep":{
              "items":{
                "oneOf":[
                  {
                    "properties":{
                      "afs_emp_rep_Capacity":{
                        "contains":{
                          "const": "Current director of licensee"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "required":[
                      "afs_emp_rep_Capacity",
                      "afs_emp_rep_verify"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "properties":{
                      "afs_emp_rep_Capacity":{
                        "not":{
                          "contains":{
                            "const":"Current director of licensee"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "required":[
                      "afs_emp_rep_Capacity"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties":{
        "report_body":{
          "properties":{
            "licensees_schemes_rep_involved":{
              "properties":{
                "report_submit_licensee":{
                  "const":"Yes"
                }
              },
              "required":[
                "report_submit_licensee"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This way, your second example fails while a modified one as below (note, it contains `afs_emp_rep_verify`) is accepted

```json
...
            {
                "afs_emp_rep_Capacity": [
                    "Current director of licensee"
                ],
                "afs_emp_rep_work_monitored": "No",
                "afs_emp_rep_verify": "No"
            },
...
```